# ATI Mobility Radion 4650 drivers on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, intel

Hi I just updated from 12.04 to 13.1 and the first thing I did was try and install the official ATI drivers from there site. After downloading while installing the drivers I get a message that says one or more tools are missing and I should see `fglrx.log`. When I open that `/lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h` cannot be found on this system. Also Ubuntu recognises the graphics card as a *Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV730* which im guessing is cause of the open source drivers. But the performance is poor and I'm asking for help to improve OpenGL gaming performance on my PC
Also are there drivers for my i5 CPU to help improve performance ?

System specs:

- Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 460 @ 2.53GHz × 4
- ATI Mobility Radion 4650
- Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems on linux mint 15, I did this:

cp /usr/include/linux/version.h /lib/modules/$(uname -r)-generic/build/include/linux/

seems to have fixed the problem for me, hope it works for you :)